# WebDriver for Windows 10 Store JS apps?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, windows-10-universal

I want to try WebDriver to test my Windows 10 JS/HTML app. I know Microsoft released [Microsoft WebDriver](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/#W9Dh27Dh2VZTE6xr.97) for their Edge browser but the code example implies it directly runs Edge rather than apps using EdgeHTML.

A code snippet from the example from [Edge blog](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/#t0CdJYR7S5HEyHuK.97):

```
driver = new EdgeDriver();  

// Navigate to Bing
driver.Url = "https://www.bing.com/";

// Find the search box and query for webdriver
var element = driver.FindElementById("sb_form_q");

element.SendKeys("webdriver");
element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Is there any guide, or is it even possible to use WebDriver test for Windows 10 JS apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any guide, or is it even possible to use WebDriver test for Windows 10 JS apps?

WebDriver supports only web application test. If you want to test windows application, you can use [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver).

And here is a video introducing WinAppDriver: [UI Test Automation for Browsers and Apps Using the WebDriver Standard](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2016/P499).

Comment: Thank you for giving me correct WinAppDriver. I have acknowledged that there is a tool named "WinAppDriver" but somehow [I got a different one which does not support Windows 10](https://github.com/imsardine/winappdriver/wiki/Getting-Started). Thank you again!

Comment: Also, the video says at 18:30 that the Selenium.Appium.iOS namespace just works for Windows apps, which is interesting :D